# sync project in netbeans both ways via ftp

Tags: php, netbeans, frameworks, ftp

I have a question about netbeans.
I made a new netbeans php project, configured it with the existing ftp settings, and it started downloading all the files to my local hd, so far everything is working correctly.

but because I'm using a php framework, which will automatically generate some files for me makes a file, it won't be synced to my local hd.

So my problem is as long as I make new files in netbeans it will work correctly, but when files are generated outside netbeans it won't.

How can I configure netbeans so it will sync both ways via ftp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't as far as I know. You have to manually right click on the project/folder you want to update and click Download or Upload. Note that this will overwrite any changes on the receiving side (e.g. downloading files will overwrite local changes and uploading files will overwrite remote file changes).

Alternatively, you can have the Upload Files On Save or On Run options enabled, but this will only work for local->remote synchronization scenario. You can access this option by right clicking your project, choosing Properties and following the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: i have configured my project as you showed on the second option, but i still have the same problem, i dont have a button wich says download/upload, i tried source->scan for external changes but it wont download any new files.

Comment: The Download/Upload options appears when you right click on a project OR a folder. I am not sure which one of both.

Comment: Problem solved, thankyou i was rightclicking my netbeans instead of my sourcefolder,
i hope they will make a automatic sync option in the future.

Comment: Netbeans has a synchronize option when you right click on "Source Files" in the project view.